# Как сокрашенно обработать explode, array_pop, implode?

Tags: php

```
$path = 'test/test2/test3'; // может быть больше значений с разделителем /

$new_path = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));
$method = array_pop($new_path); // test3
$path = implode('/', $new_path); // test/test2
```

Нужно из строки `test/test2/test3` отдельно получить `test3` и `test/test2`

Comment: вам именно этими тремя функциями надо воспользоваться, или в целом задачу решить короче?

Comment: хочу в целом короче, а то таких обработок в коде очень много

Comment: если прям таких много, то надо завести функцию, которая это делать будет и ее использовать везде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[$path, $method] = preg_split('/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/i', 'test/test2/test3');
```